# Process of Converting a MIPS Instruction to its Hex code

Tags: assembly, hex, mips

I'm trying to find an explanation online, but everything I find seems to be a conversion program someone wrote that doesn't really explain it. Looked for questions here on SO and most of it is above my pay grade, I'm looking at the very beginning of the basics. I understand the idea (I think):

```
`add $s0, $s3, $s5`
```

Isolate them like so
[image: Green sheet snippet]

And keeping in mind "rd" needs to come from the first register, $s0, convert the pieces to hex based on the [MIPS Green Sheet](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf), giving us

```
add = op code of 0  
$s3 = 19 in decimal, 13 in hex  
$s5 = 21 in decimal, 15 in hex  
$s0 = 16 in decimal, 10 in hex  
shamt = 0  
funct = 20 from add
```

This already has me lost, since it would be 0131510020... Not 8 bits. Nope.

And based on this [online converter](http://www.kurtm.net/mipsasm/index.cgi), it comes out as

```
`02758020` in hex
```

How in the world does that happen? I'm even playing with the converter, just moving up one register at a time and the changes are just confusing me further. Is there a trick to this I missed or a good resource? Every video I find is talking about machine code (binary) and never goes into the hex portion of it.

Comment: The register fields are 5 bits each.  A value may be 15 hex, but that only occupies 5 bits, not 8.

Comment: Hint:  Map it out a bit at a time in base 2.

Comment: And, of course, understand that "hex" is just talking about a human representation of a number.  The machine only sees binary bits.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean map it in base 2? I understand that each piece occupies 5 bits but how does that change its value? the number of bits it can contain only changes the maximum value it can store

Comment: Base 2 is binary.  If a piece occupies 5 bits and it's, say, 13 hex, that would be 10011.  With no extra bits.  When you glom the hex together the way you did above you get 00010011.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put it together in binary, not in hex.

The little numbers in the image tell you the amount of bits of every part.

```
add = op code of 0, 000000 in bin
$s3 = 19 in decimal, 13 in hex, 10011 in bin
$s5 = 21 in decimal, 15 in hex, 10101 in bin
$s0 = 16 in decimal, 10 in hex, 10000 in bin
shamt = 0, 00000 in bin
funct = 20 from add, 10100 in bin
```

Then put everything together and convert to hexadecimal:

0b00000010011101011000000000100000 = 0x02758020

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. So there's no straight conversion from decimal to hex that will come out properly? And also, how would I convert that by hand? Like what's a good way to do it? Great answer btw, exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: You can easily work out the binary values of each part of the instruction word by hand, they're quite small numbers. Once you have the whole instruction word, you can convert from bin to hex super easily. Every 4 bits give you one hex digit: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/how-binary-to-hex.htm

Comment: @CaptainHook - It's not the conversion between decimal and hex -- those are just different ways of writing the same value.  It's understanding that a field in the instruction is not necessarily some multiple of 4 bits.